# Mappings with measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $$f: \Omega \to \Lambda$$
with $\Omega$ being the sample space, and $\Lambda$ a simpler space (often $\Lambda = R^k$, with R being the real line.)

Let $(\Omega, F)$ and $(\Lambda, G)$ be measurable spaces. With $F$ a collection of subsets of $\Omega$, and G a collection of subsets of $\Lambda$.

I have a few questions on the mapping system as a whole.

If the measurable function $f^{-1}(G) \subset F$, does this suggest that $f(F) \subset G$?

If so, is the following happening.

1. A collection of subsets are mapped from one measurable space to another, and so the MS (measurable space) that receives the mapping, holds an additional number of subsets from another MS?
2. For the inverse image, are we only mapping those subsets that were initially mapped, otherwise, could a random mapping occur between the two? If not, does a measurable function only receive what it originally outputted?

I understand that many questions are here, but they're important to aid my understanding for measurable functions.

Comment: The answer to the first question is a clear NO.

Comment: Your questions are borderline unintelligible. Please consider reframing them so that they are less ambiguous.